# When calling a function with admin-ajax.php, what is the first parameter?

Tags: functions, ajax, actions, parameter

I'm trying to make a function that can either be called directly or via admin-ajax.php.

Strangely, when calling it as an AJAX function, the first parameter's value is a blank string.

```
function my_function($foo = 10, $bar = 10)
{
    //$foo will have a different value here depending on whether the function was called directly or via AJAX. Why?
    //$bar will always correctly default to 10
}
```

Why is it being passed a blank string, and where's the documentation for this?

Comment: Well how are you calling the function, in both cases? There's no example.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - I'm just calling the AJAX function normally.